# How does Swift deal with constant values into mathematical functions?

Tags: swift

I realize that this is not a big issue but I am curious. I have a function `func radian(degree: CGFloat)->CGFloat` that as suggested multiplies the input by the necessary value to convert the degree into a radian.

I have peppered my code with references to this function that have constant values. In a given main loop this function will get called with constant parameters (like `radian(360)`) at least a few thousand times.

I realize doing multiplication a few thousand times on modern processors is not an issue but I would still like to understand how the Swift compiler works.

I am debating whether to go back and put the result of this function in as a hard-coded value rather than a call to the function. My gut feeling is that the compiler will do this automatically for me but I wanted to make sure that was true.

Does the compiler compile `radian(360)` into `6.283184`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is likely to inline the call, and once the call is inlined, it's also likely to perform constant-folding in order to do the calculation at compile-time.

So yes, with optimizations enabled, it's reasonably likely that `radian(360)` will be compiled into `6.283184`. But the only way to verify this is to actually look at the resulting assembly of an optimized build.

If you want to make this even more likely, you can stick the undocumented `@inline(__always)` attribute on your function. That will force it to always inline the function. But this is probably unnecessary.